# Get-AzureRmWebApp: filtering results has unexpected behavior

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I type the following in Powershell, to list the names of all of my azure web applications:

```
Get-AzureRmWebApp | % { $_.Name }
```

It outputs:

```
coolum-exercise-web-app
practice-web-app
AzureSandbox
```

But then I want to filter this output on the name. I type this:

```
Get-AzureRmWebApp | ? { $_.Name -like "coolum-exercise-web-app" } | % { $_.Name }
```

I expect to see only one output. Instead I see

```
coolum-exercise-web-app
practice-web-app
AzureSandbox
```

Why didn't the name filter get applied?

If I use the `-Name` parameter directly on `Get-AzureRmWebApp` it works:

```
Get-AzureRmWebApp -Name "coolum-exercise-web-app" | % { %_.Name }
```

Outputs:

```
coolum-exercise-web-app
```

But why does `where-object` fail to apply the filter as expected?

---

And here's some really puzzling behavior: if you wrap `Get-AzureRmWebApp` in brackets, the filter works as you would expect it to.

```
(Get-AzureRmWebApp) | ? { $_.Name -like "coolum-exercise-web-app" } | % { $_.Name }
```

Outputs:

```
coolum-exercise-web-app
```

Can anyone explain this behavior? Why would enclosing the command in brackets make the filtering work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug: [#1544 Get-AzureRmWebApp - unable to pipe into select-object](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/1544)

The results of `Get-AzureRmWebApp` is a list. You would expect each item of the list to be sent through the pipe item-by-item. Instead, the entire list gets sent through the pipe once, as a single object.

To demonstrate:

```
 Get-AzureRmWebApp | % { $_.GetType().FullName }
```

Displays

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.Site, Microsoft.Azure.Management.Websites, Version=1.0.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]
```

While

```
(Get-AzureRmWebApp) | % { $_.GetType().FullName }
```

Displays

```
Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.Site
Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.Site
Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.Site
```

The bug happens because the underlying C# code invokes [WriteObject(sendToPipeline = list)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms568371(v=vs.85).aspx), when it should invoke [WriteObject(sendToPipeline = list, enumerateCollection = true)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms568370(v=vs.85).aspx)

---

The act of wrapping the call in brackets assigns the returned list to a local temporary object. This local temporary object then behaves like a normal list.

I hope the Azure team fix this, because there will be unintended consequences for hapless automation script writers.

For example, my original call:

```
Get-AzureRmWebApp | ? { $_.Name -like "coolum-exercise-web-app" } | % { $_.Name }
```

gets interpreted as "If **any** of the values has a `Name` like `coolum-exercise-web-app`, then display all of the values."

---

**Edit (March 2019)**

I have tested this with the [Azure Az Powershell Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-1.4.0&fbclid=IwAR3URoAyhnPL9JIM8rwrOUFrTWQVY7edDD4T5Vexk_lhBbrNQLLpQdfvQwU) and I can see this problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with: (notice the brackets)

```
(Get-AzureRmWebApp) | ? { $_.Name -like 'cool*' }
```

<del>Looks like the whole where clause is considered as the default named parameter to Get-AzureRmWebApp. That's why you have to seperate the CmdLet from the where clause with brackets.</del>

Actually Get-AzureRmWebApp returns a list, whereas other CmdLet like Get-AzureRmVM returns a single object.

```
Get-AzureRmWebApp | gm
Get-AzureRmVM | gm
```